# jQuery : which is faster in this case (.find) vs (.filter)

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I have a big table, containing lots of lines (50-200) and columns (30). So in total I have at least 1500 cells. I want to know which of the following instructions are faster and why?

```
//assuming we have some predefined variable
var table = $('#myTable');
var allCells = table.find('td');
```

If a selected cell have a class `selected`

```
selectedCells = table.find('td.selected');
```

vs

```
selectedCells = allCells.filter('.selected');
```

Or is there a better, native javascript way (in term of performance and readability) to find selected cells considering you have 1500 cells to loop through?

Comment: Try it yourself: http://jsperf.com/.

Comment: @FelixKling I don't know how to use it, can you do that for me?

Comment: Have a look at an existing test, e.g. http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-vs-standard-selector.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/find-v-filter

Comment: http://jsperf.com/find-v-filter/2, which includes this third case: `var selectedCells = table.find('td').filter('.selected');`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`find()` here will be faster as your `filter()` method relies on `find()` anyway. From your code:

```js
var allCells = table.find('td');

selectedCells = allCells.filter('.selected');
```

`table.find('td.selected');` pulls only the `td` elements with the `selected` class.

`table.find('td').filter('.selected')` pulls *all* the `td` elements then filters only the elements with the `selected` class.

Comment: Why does `.filter` rely on `.find`?

Comment: @FelixKling it doesn't. Filter relies on a set of pre-selected objects. In this case, those objects have been selected using `find()`. "Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test." http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: Ok, so you meant only in this context the OP is doing a `.find` before `.filter` (this can be easily misunderstood though, I think I missed "your" in "your `filter()` method"). I was under the assumption the the OP will *always* execute `var allCells = table.find('td');` anyway, so using `.filter` would be better than using search for the cells again with `.find`. But who knows :)